# Having trouble cycling through background colors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to animate the background color the way the text does in this script.  It does a fine job of slowly cycling through colors, but the script only applies this effect to a Span tag, and I'd like it to apply to the Body tag.  I tried applying "sp1" to the Body, and even trying to put the whole page into a big Div and apply it there, but it doesn't work.  Anyone have any ideas?

I'm not going to clog up this post with all the code because it's just a view-source of this page:

http://www.javascript-fx.com/development/colorcycle/spancycle.html

Thank you very much, anyone who can lend some direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post kind of cuts out:

> is effect to a , and I'd like it to apply to the .

I assume you want to do the background rather than the text color, correct?  If so change the line:

```
faderObj[i].style.color = getColor(start, end, index);
```

to:

```
faderObj[i].style.backgroundColor = getColor(start, end, index);
```

Otherwise, please clarify.

Comment: apparently I had the word Body in brackets, since it's a tag, and it got formatted out...  I fixed it.  But I think you answered my question anyway!  Thank you!